# Python: Encoding issue using re.sub

Tags: python, encoding

actually, I'm testing some substitutions in html-files with the following code:

```
text = re.sub(u'<div class="paragraph" style="[^"]+"><span class="font61"><i>Test. </i>55<span class="font16"></span><span style=" letter-spacing:-0.70pt;"> </span></span></div>', u'<div class="paragraph" style="\1"><span class="font61"><i>Test.</i><span class="font16"></span><span style=" letter-spacing:-0.70pt;">55</span></span></div>', text)
```

Unfortunately, my output is:

```
 <div class="paragraph" style=""><span class="font61"><i>Test. </i><span class="font16"></span><span style="
 letter-spacing:-0.70pt;">55</span></span></div>
```

Instead of `"style=" padding:6.00pt 63.36pt 0.00pt 43.68pt; text-align:justify;""`, I receive a special character, which also cannot be displayed here. How can I fix this problem?

In other words:
If I have something like:

```
<div class="paragraph" style=" padding:0.00pt 0.00pt 0.00pt 90.24pt; text-align:left;"><span class="font61"><i>Test </i>55<span class="font16"></span><span style=" letter-spacing:-0.70pt;"> </span></span></div>
```

(The important thing is: < /i> + number + < span class = ), I'd like to move the number to the last gap (here, before < /span> ).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.sub()` is doing what it has been told.

Assuming that you have entered the replacement string correctly in your question, the "special character" `"\x01"` is within your replacement string (2nd argument to `re.sub()`):

```
u'<div class="paragraph" style="\x01">.........'
```

Try changing your replacement string to:

```
u'<div class="paragraph" style="padding:6.00pt 63.36pt 0.00pt 43.68pt; text-align:justify;"><span class="font61"><i>Test.</i><span class="font16"></span><span style=" letter-spacing:-0.70pt;">55</span></span></div>'
```

However, you are probably better off using a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to help you parse and process the HTML, rather than use regular expressions.

Comment: @MarkF6 this answer is correct, except that the literal character sequence isn't `\x01` it's `\1`. Use `\\1` or use a raw string literal `ur'\1'`.